# Visual Studio does not differentiate between C headers and C++ headers

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, header

I am work with C language with **Visual Studio 2017-enterprise** but there is a complex problem with C header files because Visual Studio considers every header
is a C++ header. So, whether the extension is `.hpp` or `.h`, it will treat it as a C++ header,
and this causes problem because I used C99 and Visual Studio will consider the header is C++ so I can't use C features in the header file.

***Note***:  When I name a source file to `.c`, Visual Studio treats it as a C file, not C++, and it's good. So I need to do the same with headers.
**I need to make .h for c and .hpp for c++ How?**

This problem also with VS 2010, 2013, 2015.

**EDIT::**

> the problem with highlighting  for example if i create class in .c
>   file visula studio will say there is error but this will not show any
>   error if i create class in .h file even if i use extern"C"

look At This image :
[source.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6J91.png)
Now Look At This
[source.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IiRX.png)

Comment: Everything depends from where you call your header files. Consider using `extern "C"` for C code. This is not a problem in any of the versions you mentioned. It works as expected for C and for C++ separatelly. If you include .h file from .cpp then you have miss treats.

Comment: a header file is not a compilation unit.

Comment: Header is not compiled as C or C++. Source files are compiled. If some header has to be included in c and c++ source code files - use #ifdef __cplusplus

Comment: What kind of C features are you missing? Syntax highlighting? Code completion?

Comment: Can you create an MCVE ([MCVE]) illustrating the problem you face?  You'd need an example of a header that contains the C99 feature that the C compiler supports but the C++ compiler rejects, and you'd need to show a C program that uses that header, and the exact error messages from the exact command line that is executed when you compile that C code with that header.

Comment: "... so I can't use C features in the header file." do you maybe confuse some error highlighting of your IDE with real errors ?

Comment: tobi303 : exactly : i have problem with highlighting  for example if i create class in .c file visula studio will say there is error but this will not show any error if i create class in .h file even if i use extern"C"

Comment: @MR.ASKER That is because a header file is language agnostic.  Since MSVS is a C++ compiler by default so it is going to use C++ syntax highlighting in header files.

Comment: ...but then it is not true that you cant use c++ features. It is just the code highlighting that is wrong. Anyhow I would not rely on the IDE for errors, but always ask my compiler. If it is just a matter of annoyance, I would simply turn it off

Answer (score 2):

If you `#include` a `.h` file from a `.c` file then Visual Studio will compile it as C.  If you `#include` a `.h` file from a `.cpp` file then Visual Studio will compile it as C++.

It's common to do this in C-specific headers:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

void MyCFunction();
void MyCFunction2();

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

This allows you to declare functions which are implemented in C. Other C-sources can use these functions, and C++ sources can use these functions.

You don't really need to worry about C++-specific headers because you'll just get compilation errors if you `#include` them in a C source.

Comment: the problem with highlighting

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having as I understand it is that you are trying to develop C code in vscode, however the editor keeps trying to treat `*.h` files as `C++` files and not `C` files, fundamentally this is because as far as I can tell MS hates `C`. I had the same problem, so here is the solution I ended up using:

1. Open the command palette by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`
2. Start typing `Preferences: Configure language specific settings`
3. Choose `C`, this will open `Settings.json`
4. If the key `"files.associations"` isn't defined, you'll have to define it, and add the `"*.h": "c",` property in it.

At the end the file should look like this:

```json
{
    //...other settings

    "files.associations": {
        "*.h": "c",
    },

    //...other settings
}
```

This will set the editor mode to `C` whenever you open a file ending with a `.h`. You can define similar settings for [all these languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers).

Answer (score -1):

"This causes problem because I used C99 and Visual Studio will consider the header is C++ so I can't use C features in the header file."

No, the problem is that Visual Studio does not support C99 anywhere, neither in header files nor in .C files. Visual Studio follows ISO C90.

Comment: ok : but i still need visual studio as syntax highlighter only : so i need it to consider .h is a c file and .hpp as cpp file is ther any solution Or i will need to create vs-plugin to do this?

Comment: @Rihcodo: The VS highlighter uses C++ rules regardless of the source. Try ` int class`, perfectly valid in C89.